# FFMPEG and Bitrates

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

My goal is to figure out the most effective way of forwarding/restreaming a video in the m3u8 format by using FFMPEG. I do not mind bearing the cost of a CDN or extra servers however the ultimate goal is to deliver content at the following specification;

- 1280x720
- 30 FPS
- 1Mbit/s (1,000Kbits)

During the testing phase I am using the following placeholders:

```
Input: https://adultswimhls-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/238460/adultswim/main/1/master.m3u8
Output: rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xfiles
```

The current command I am using is;

```
ffmpeg -re -i https://adultswimhls-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/238460/adultswim/main/1/master.m3u8 -c:a aac -c:v copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xfiles
```

[Current Resource Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ULwm.png)

After doing some research on SuperUser and a few other domains I believe that the `-c:v copy` argument effectively mirrors the input source meaning my server is not re-encoding hence why the CPU usage is so light.

The second that I use a command like;

```
ffmpeg -re -i https://adultswimhls-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/238460/adultswim/main/1/master.m3u8 -c:a aac -b:v 1M -b:a XXX -r 30 -s 1280x720 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xfiles (Not tested if this actually works, but just an example)
```

I notice the 5%~ CPU usage from the first command soon turns into a solid 60%+ and I am guessing thats because I am actually re-encoding. I am taking the input stream, applying said variables to it then re-encoding and pushing it to the desination which is understandable and upgrading my server is not an issue however I have to find out if I am ballsing something up. This is my first time using FFMPEG and I have done all the research I can possibly bring myself round to understanding hence why I am asking for somebody who knows their stuff. My thoughts are:

- Find a CDN that offers encoding, waiting to hear back from BelugaCDN, I know one CDN provider offered it to me for $10 a month which was good, forgot which one though.
- Seek for help in optimising the second command or finding someway to use `-c:v copy` and lower the bitrate to 1Mbit/s which I don't think is possible.
- Work out if its possible (not sure if anybody would know this or its more service based) to input the native bitrate stream when using a CDN but limit the outbound bitrate so the viewers are not sucking up crazy 5Mbit/s worth of bandwidth as the stream itself does not need to be that high of quality.
- Upgrade my server so I can handle up to 3 simultaneous streams with me re-encoding, if so what specifications would I be looking to aim for.

Now I know you're likely thinking just use YouTube/Twitch its free... Well the video I am offering is a paid service and it just looks unprofessional therefore that would be my last resort.

Thank you for any help/advice.

Comment: There are services such as Mux.com that do all this.

Comment: I am looking into FFMPEG tweaks prior to reaching out to CDN's, even then Mux seems rather expensive compared to other solutions I have found.

Comment: Yeah, it’s not cheep. But transcoding isn’t whether you buy a computer or rent one, it takes a lot of CPU to change the bitrate of a video.

Comment: Note that depending on configuration you may hit the performance limit of your machine, aka it will no longer process 'real time'. There are various encoder options like multi-threading and real-time goal that can be enabled. Note that especially the latter lower quality in favor of fitting the time and bandwidth constraint.

Comment: @TBR, I was actually focusing on the wrong thing. After seeking advice from my server provider it turned out the load when running one encoder was between 0.5-1.0 with my "recommended" allowance being 3.0. I did not realise how CPU intensive re-encoding actually was. I am looking into my options of optimising the ffmpeg command above if you have any suggestions.